# DATEDIFF excluding summer months

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are running reports for a seasonal business, with expected lulls during the summer months.  For some metrics, we'd essentially like to pretend that those months don't even exist.

Thus consider the default behavior of:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01') -- answer = 1
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-07-01') -- 2
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-08-01') -- 3
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-09-01') -- 4
```

We want to ignore June and July, so we would *like* those answers to look like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01') -- answer = 1
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-07-01') -- 1
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-08-01') -- 1
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2015-05-01', '2015-09-01') -- 2
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I'd like a pure SQL solution, rather than something using TSQL, but writing a custom function such as `NOSUMMER_DATEDIFF` could also work.

Also, keep in mind the reports will span multiple years, so the solution should be able to handle that.

Comment: You have to create `summer months` table, then to exclude months which are in this table. That's all.

Comment: This is the basis of all calendar tables. What do you mean by pure SQL instead of t-sql? Aren't you doing this in sql server?

Comment: @MaciejLos, I don't fully understand your suggestion?  The input is still a "start_date" and "end_date", and the output is the time elapsed in months between the two, not counting and summer months.  How would I use the excluded_months table you are suggesting to solve this?

Comment: @Jonah, i'm working on sample. When i finish, i'll let you know.

Comment: @SeanLange, The query needs to able to be run by sales guys, through a web interface that only allows SQL statements.  However, the web interface would also have access to custom functions.

Comment: A web interface that allows SQL Statements !?! O_O

Comment: Making a specialized function looks to be the right direction.

Comment: What do you want for output when the starting and ending months are both summer months? What is the definition of summer months?

Comment: @SeanLange, 0 would be fine for that edge case, though it doesn't really matter.  As in the examples from my OP, summer months = June and July for our purposes.

Comment: Only June and July? I am not quite sure what you want to do here to be honest. I don't think DATEDIFF is the function you want though because it counts the number of thresholds that are crossed.

Comment: Are all of your parameter values going to be the first of a given month or do you need to deal with specific dates like 2015-05-15?

Comment: Yes, only June and July.  Parameter values could be anything.  If DATEDIFF works by how many 1st of months are crossed, then you are correct: we don't want that.  We would instead want something like  `(days between start and end date) / 30`, rounded down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested month differences, then I would suggest a trick here.  Count the number of months since some date 0, but ignore the summer months.  For example:

```
'2015-05-01' --> 2015 * 10 + 5 = 20155
'2015-06-01' --> 2015 * 10 + 6 = 20156
'2015-07-01' --> 2015 * 10 + 6 = 20156
'2015-08-01' --> 2015 * 10 + 6 = 20156
'2015-09-01' --> 2015 * 10 + 7 = 20157
```

This is a fairly easy calculation:

```
select (case when month(date2) <= 6 then  year(date2) * 10 + month(date2)
             when month(date2) in (7, 8) then year(date2) * 10 + 6
             else year(date2) * 10 + (month(date2) - 2)
        end)
```

For the difference:

```
select ((case when month(date2) <= 6 then  year(date2) * 10 + month(date2)
              when month(date2) in (7, 8) then year(date2) * 10 + 6
              else year(date2) * 10 + (month(date2) - 2)
         end) -
        (case when month(date1) <= 6 then  year(date1) * 10 + month(date1)
              when month(date1) in (7, 8) then year(date1) * 10 + 6
              else year(date1) * 10 + (month(date1) - 2)
         end)
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

To able to achieve that, you have to "split" dates ranges to an "array" of dates for every single range of dates. [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) might be helpful in this case.

See:

```
--your table which holds dates ranges
DECLARE @dates TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), dFrom DATE, dTo DATE)
INSERT INTO @dates (dFrom, dTo)
VALUES('2015-05-01', '2015-06-01'),
('2015-05-01', '2015-07-01'),
('2015-05-01', '2015-08-01'),
('2015-05-01', '2015-09-01')

--summer month table
DECLARE @summermonths TABLE(summMonth INT)
INSERT INTO @summermonths(summMonth)
VALUES(6), (7)

--here Common Table Expressions is in action to "split" dates ranges to an array of dates for every single date range
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, DATEADD(MM, 0, dFrom) AS ndFrom, dTo, CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(MM, 0, dFrom)) = 6 OR MONTH(DATEADD(MM, 0, dFrom)) = 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS COfMonth  
    FROM @dates 
    WHERE DATEADD(MM, 1, dFrom)<=dTo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, DATEADD(MM, 1, ndFrom)  AS ndFrom,  dTo, CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(MM, 1, ndFrom)) = 6 OR MONTH(DATEADD(MM, 1, ndFrom)) = 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS COfMonth
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MM, 1, ndFrom)<=dTo
) 
SELECT t1.id, t2.dFrom, t2.dTo, SUM(t1.COfMonth) AS MyDateDiff 
FROM CTE AS t1 INNER JOIN @dates AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.dFrom , t2.dTo
```

Result:

```
id  dFrom       dTo         MyDateDiff
1   2015-05-01  2015-06-01  1
2   2015-05-01  2015-07-01  1
3   2015-05-01  2015-08-01  2
4   2015-05-01  2015-09-01  3 --not 2, because of 5, 8, 9
```

Got it?

Note: a solution might be differ in case of `dFrom` and `dTo` is not the first date of month.